# ReactJs Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have react js code of inner most child  component  like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { addToCart } from 'actions/cart'


export default (props) => {
  const { line_item, cart} = props
  // const oClick = line_item.oClick.bind(line_item)
const handleClick = (id) =>   this.props.dispatch(addToCart(id, 1))
 // *I am getting error above line*
  return (
  <div>
  <ul className="ul-reset">
    <li>
      <div className="cart-prod-wrapper cf">
        <div className="cart-image-wrapper">
          <div className="cart-image">
              <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Product One"/>
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-details">
          <div className="cart-name">
            <a href="#">{line_item.variant.name}</a>
          </div>
          <div className="cart-price">{line_item.variant.price}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-qty">
          <div className="cart-qty-name">QTY:</div>
          <div className="cart-qty-value">
            <div class="minus"><span>-</span></div>
          {line_item.quantity}
          <div class="plus">
 <span value = { line_item.variant.id } onClick={handleClick(line_item.variant.id)}  >+</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="cart-total">
          <div className="cart-total-name">Total</div>
          <div className="cart-total-value">{line_item.variant.price * line_item.quantity}</div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
      )
    }
```

i want to perform to call an action using dispatch

and code of parent presentation component is line

```
export default (props) => {


const { account, cart, readMore1} = props

 return (

<li>

{ !cart.isFetching && cart.line_items.map( 
  (line_item, i) => <CartPreview key = {i} line_item= {line_item} cart ={cart}   />)  
} 

</li>
 )
 }
```

can any on please guide me to solve this error

Edit

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
account: getAccount(state),
cart: getCart(state),
classToSend: getReadmore(state),
authenticityToken: getAuthenticityToken(state)
}
```

}

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeaderContainer)
```

Comment: Get rid of the `this`, you're in a stateless component: `props.dispatch`.

Comment: @AndrewLi  error      TypeError: props.dispatch is not a function,if remove this.

Comment: Are you mapping dispatch to props?

Comment: Adding to that, please note you're executing `handleClick` instead of passing it as argument on the `onClick`

Comment: @AndrewLi yes that already done

Comment: @Anish Can I see how?

Comment: @Patrick which other way I can do that...??

Comment: @Anish You could use bind, wrap it in another function, preferably arrow.

Comment: @AndrewLi please see edits

Comment: @Anish You're never mapping dispatch to props...

Comment: can you please show me how to do that in Header Container page

Comment: @AndrewLi i did like onClick={() => handleClick()}, but error persist, how to map dispatch here

Comment: @AndrewLi you there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this could help

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux' // import connect from redux
import { addToCart } from 'actions/cart'

// name component to wrap it with connect
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { line_item, cart} = props
  return (
  <div>
  <ul className="ul-reset">
    <li>
      <div className="cart-prod-wrapper cf">
        <div className="cart-image-wrapper">
          <div className="cart-image">
              <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Product One"/>
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-details">
          <div className="cart-name">
            <a href="#">{line_item.variant.name}</a>
          </div>
          <div className="cart-price">{line_item.variant.price}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-qty">
          <div className="cart-qty-name">QTY:</div>
          <div className="cart-qty-value">
            <div class="minus"><span>-</span></div>
          {line_item.quantity}
          <div class="plus">
           // used arrow function 
            <span value = { line_item.variant.id } onClick={() => props.dispatch(addToCart(line_item.variant.id, 1)}  >+</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="cart-total">
          <div className="cart-total-name">Total</div>
          <div className="cart-total-value">{line_item.variant.price * line_item.quantity}</div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      )
}

export default connect()(MyComponent); // connect dispatch to component
```

Comment: its a presentation component in parent component i already use "connect" still i need to use it , why???

Comment: Actually you need to connect any component that needs to interact with the store in this case you are dispatching addToCart action. if this is the presentational component and you don't want to connect this component to store you will have to pass method to this component from the connected parent component and do the required dispatch action in parent component :) .